# How to create a migration to insert initial data into a table?

Tags: python, django, django-south

So this is my model:

```
class Config(models.Model):
    config_key = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    config_value = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

I have created an initial migration with:

```
python manage.py schemamigration myapp --initial
```

But now I would like to insert some initial data inside the config table and create a migration that inserts that data (basically it will run on insert sql query).

How to do it?

Comment: Are you looking for `Data migrations` (http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/part3.html#data-migrations)?

Comment: Your first `syncdb` command will insert any fixtures data Django finds (see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/initial-data/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
python manage.py datamigration myapp name_migration
```